# Parallel-compilation: MSBuild with make - Dependencies not called

Tags: msbuild, parallel-processing, makefile

I've got a little problem with a parallelized compilation.

I've got more than 200 projects developed with Visual Studio 2010 in a solution.
I would like to test parallelized compilation using Make in order to compare with Visual Studio compilation.

All of the structure of Makefile is correct. And I use this command for MSBuild.

`msbuild.exe  $(1).vcxproj -t:Build -p:Configuration=$(VS_CONFIG) -nologo -clp:NoSummary\;ShowCommandLine -p:BuildProjectReferences=false`

I call `make -j4 all` in order to build my application but I've got the impression that Make don't build the dependencies of my projects in the Makefile.dependencies.

I've got this message :

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'dependency.lib' [C:\project.vcxproj]`

The dependency in question is not built during the process when the project needs it.
So, do you have an idea to resolve my problem ? Because it's really weird...

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I have to put .PHONY in my case because targets of Makefile have the same name of directories.
Bye!